# Flex application logout (siteminder used for authentication)

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, logout, siteminder

I'm working on a  Flex 3.5 web app with Siteminder authentication and I have some problems with logout and IE9.

On click on logout button I call

siteminder.xxx.it/siteminderagent/xxx-logout.fcc/

and the first logout makes these calls

*302    HTTP    siteminder.xxx.it   /siteminderagent/xxx-logout.fcc/    313 no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080

302 HTTP    xxx.yyy.it  /client-web 461 no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080

200 HTTP    siteminder.xxx.it   /siteminderagent/mylogin.fcc?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-00006cf6-458d-1d40-964a-0265c0a85024&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-yx%2fRAnRmsQJxM%2fCmccgQ4%2bXx0vaGseQ3Fsv1KWcytAoO6LfYuVpjXDQ6XkxgUsWf&TARGET=-SM-http%3a%2f%2fxxx%2eyyy%2eit%2fclient--web 2.897   no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080

302 HTTP    siteminder.xxx.it   /siteminderagent/xxx-logout.fcc 313 no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080

302 HTTP    xxx.yyy.it  /client-web 461 no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080

200 HTTP    siteminder.xxx.it   /siteminderagent/mylogin.fcc?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-00006cf6-458d-1d40-964a-0265c0a85024&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-yx%2fRAnRmsQJxM%2fCmccgQ4%2bXx0vaGseQ3Fsv1KWcytAoO6LfYuVpjXDQ6XkxgUsWf&TARGET=-SM-http%3a%2f%2fxxx%2eyyy%2eit%2fclient--web 2.897   no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:40080*

If I make again the login on siteminder, I'm correctly redirected to my flex web app. The next logout doesn't work because seems that IE) ignore this 302 redirect

*302    HTTP    siteminder.xxx.it   /siteminderagent/xxx-logout.fcc/    313 no-store    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1   iexplore:36916*

From fiddler I can see that the response of this call is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://xxx.yyy.it/client-web">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at siteminder.xxx.it Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

On cache tab i can see

Cache-Control : no-store
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 16:03:54 GMT

Why IE9 doesn't read correctly this 302 redirect ?

NOTE : If I disable IE cache, all works correctly !!

Comment: Does the comment on this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702112/http-302-redirects-between-servers-failing-in-ie-working-in-ff-and-chrome [AKA Could it just be your security settings in IE?]

Comment: I will try to change this option thank you ... I have added also an important note !

Comment: It isn't a problem of security setting in IE