# AngularJS Interceptor for HTTP 302 is not working on IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I am calling authentication service that returns HTTP 302 to signal redirect. To handle this, I have Angular http interceptor that checks for the status code and acts accordingly.

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
  if (rejection.status === 302) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:moved-http', rejection);
  } else if (rejection.status === 404) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:notfound-http', rejection);
  }

  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

This is working perfectly in Chrome. However when using IE11, the status 302 is never passed to this interceptor. In IE, the status in the rejection object is always 0 and the data is empty ("").

Is this another Angular IE issue? Is there a way to get the 302 status in IE?

Comment: I had the same problem. Workarounded by changing sever to return `401` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently, it is not related to Angular.

It is probably another overzealous IE security configuration issue. Try:

- [HTTP 302 redirects between servers failing in IE, working in FF and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702112/http-302-redirects-between-servers-failing-in-ie-working-in-ff-and-chrome#comment24076592_16702112)

  <sub>Internet Options `>` Security `>` Local intranet `>` Sites `>` Automatically detect intranet network</sub>
- [IE does not follow a 302 redirect properly from a proxy over SSL](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/ie-does-not-follow-a-302-redirect-properly-from-a/c2d42c13-7da7-496f-9f4f-13805ed21074)

  <sub>Internet Options `>` Security `>` Reset all zones to default level</sub>